# How do I get to the bottom of a column to apply a formuale other than dragging

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, keyboard-shortcuts, spreadsheet

I am dragging corner cell in spreadsheets to apply a formula to cells in a column, fine when there are only a few rows but, is there a way to quickly move to the bottom of a column to ap[ply the formula.

Comment: If there's data next to your column a simple double click on the right bottom corner fills the formula up to the other columns last value. (If there's blanks in between it breaks from there).

Comment: Not sure if Google sheets behaves the same though.

Comment: Otherwise (in excel) you could copy the formula cell and hold `ctrl+shift` and click arrow-down and `ctrl+P` (paste).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper way would be to use `ARRAYFORMULA` in the first cell which will auto-populate for the rest of the column

otherwise:

select the first cell and press

```
CTRL + SHIFT + ARROW DOWN
```

then press

```
CTRL + ENTER
```